# JSON stringify showing empty result for java script object array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, stringify

it's somewhat confusing for me I am getting result through my ajax call I am converting that into my user defined object script and I am pushing that result into array and I am converting that into JSOn data like this

```
function orgNameAndIdListClass(id, name) {
  this.label = name;
  this.value = name;
  this.idValue = id;
}
orgNameAndIdList = [];



$.get("../organizationSourceMapping/listOrg.htm?sourceMasterFilter=",
function(response) {
  if (response.status == "LIST_SUCCESS") {
    var listOrgIdAndName = response.successObject.listOrgIdAndName;
    for (var i = 0; i < listOrgIdAndName.length; i++) {
      var orgNameIds = new orgNameAndIdListClass(listOrgIdAndName[i].id, listOrgIdAndName[i].organizationFullName);
      orgNameAndIdList.push(orgNameIds);
    }
  }, 'json')
.fail(function(response) {
  $('#page-wrapper').mask(
    response.status + "**********" + response.statusText);
}); console.log(JSON.stringify(orgNameAndIdList))

});


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

my orgNameAndIdList each object shows data like

```
idValue:1
label:"org1"
value:"org1"
```

Comment: what is listOrgIdAndName ? if it's an array then you have to loop through the array and then create the new object

Comment: And can you explain a bit more on what you are expecting

Comment: Can we see more code than what you provided.... I think the issue might be asynchronous related and not related to this code.

Comment: @epascarello:added full code please ignore parentheses  mismatch it may due to I removed redundant code

Comment: And I was right.... You ordered a pizza on the phone and as soon as you hang up you try to eat the pizza you just ordered. You did not wait for it to be delivered. That is what the callback is for.